# why current flow through ground wires of submersible 3 phase motor?

Tags: current, ground

I have a 150 KW 3-phase submersible motor with 2 cables. Each cable is (3p + 1 ground).

When connected the 2 ground wires at the same point, I read about 15 A on the ground cable. Why current flow through ground wires of submersible 3 phase motor?
I check this for many motors in different places and I found the same result.

Comment: What are you reading on each of the 3 phases?

Comment: 190, 210, 220 A

Comment: Current unbalance varying from 6% up to 30% in sometimes

Comment: What voltage are the motors?  What type of cable?  Has it seen hard use(even things like wrenching of connectors during install.  Are you able to check wiring of the motor?  Source imbalance, load imbalance, conductor impedance imbalance and short to ground are all possible.  Are the conductors used as a parallel run?  If not, why are there 2 of them?  If those are actually both ground conductors, they should probably be terminated in common on the motor end.  Be cautious as you may have a short to ground.  You should follow Stainless' advice and meggar.

Comment: This is a submersible pump with integrated motor and it's supplied with 2 cables, each one is 4 wires ( 3 power & 1 ground). The motor is 3 phase, 50 Hz, 3 x 380 V, 150 KW. I tested the motor before starting phase to phase , phase to ground, and test the insulation by megger phase to ground and it was 550 Mega ohm. The two ground wire are terminated in common on the motor end and on ground bar in the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

If a 3-phase motor is powered through a variable frequency drive (VFD), there can be some ground-fault current due to capacitive coupling between the stator winding and the motor core. However, I would expect that to be a much lower current, and you have not mentioned a VFD. If this is a new installation, I would suspect a wiring error. The ground wires should be connected only to the motor frame at the motor and only to an earth ground or grounded bus at the source.

Comment: This is a new installation without VFD. the reading current on on earth cable is 15 A and the rated current of this motor is 260 A.
when i tested this situation in many installation i found the same. there is a current reading on ground cable

Comment: @ Charles Could the 3 phases be imbalanced amplitudes?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, ground conductors are not neutral conductors. They should be connected to earth at only one point in a facility and connected to enclosures etc. that are not connected to power. A grounded neutral should be connected to ground in only one point in a facility. Phase imbalance should cause currents only in neutral conductors, not ground conductors.

Comment: @CharlesCowie 
does the voltage between neutral and earth affect on it?
the voltage between neutral and earth is 20V

Comment: An AC motor either has no neutral or has a neutral that is either not accessible in the junction box or in the box but never connected to ground or anything outside the motor. The voltage from the neutral to ground is irrelevant.